# How do i make action happen to specific, but repeated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a specific action (keyframe animation and show text) happen on `.hover` on a specific image, but when i hover it happens to all of the images.

the closest answer i could find was this

```
  $(document).click(function(event){
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

I took off the alert and changed with the right code, but wasn't able to get it to work.

here is the jsfiddle - i didn't change the pictures for other elements because i don't know how to make it work around, but feel free to do it if necessary.

https://jsfiddle.net/8746s0v5/2/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *this* keyword:

```
$('.artista img').mouseenter(function(event){
  $(this).closest('.artista').find('h3').show();
  $(this).addClass('bounce');
});

$('.artista img').mouseleave(function(event){
   $(this).closest('.artista').find('h3').hide();
  $(this).removeClass('bounce');
});
```

Comment: That helped a lot, it definitely worked, but now when it hovers on the specific one, the other images go down, as if the top margin got bigger, do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: because of _inline-block_. I am not sure exactly why, but if you put `display: flex;
justify-content: center;` on parent(#artistas) it should be fine.